# Select IP address from SQL Server column

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

I'm getting an output from one of our scripts that sends over IP address mixed with Host-names, so what I'm trying to do is setup a query that will differentiate the IPs from the Host-names so I can try to resolve the using Powershell (or something else) later.  My question is, how can I select only the IP addresses from the row when my data looks something like below (just making stuff up to get the point out there).

```
host123.na.root.net
host123.na.root.net
123.123.123.123
11.22.123.23
host789
host789
123.123.123.123
111.23.23.132
```

What I would want to get back would be just

```
11.22.123.23
123.123.123.123
111.23.23.132
```

**Edit** I've seen some things suggesting `PARSENAME`, however I'm not sure how that would work with the FQDN being in there.

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on the reference to `parsename()`, I am assuming SQL Server:

```
where ip like '%.%.%.%' and        -- has three periods
      ip not like '%.%.%.%.%' and  -- does not have four periods
      ip not like '%[^0-9.]%'      -- has only numbers and periods
```

In almost any other database, you can use a regular expression.

Comment: Thanks, your correct it's MSSQL, worked like a charm!

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest something like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT address
FROM your_table
WHERE ISNUMERIC(REPLACE(address,'.',''))=1
```

Comment: I be willing to bet that this would work in other DB's, although in MSSQL it returns an INT and not a BOOLEAN so it spits back an error.

Comment: You may be missing the =1 part at the end. ISNUMERIC returns a 1 if it is numeric, or a 0 if it is not

Comment: Careful, ISNUMERIC can return interesting results. Try it on 1e or just $. When possible (SQL 2012+) use TRY_CONVERT